# Make sure all dependent @Inputs are available in child Angular component

Tags: angular, typescript

Method in my NG component depends on 2 `@Input` props and route change subscription. Current implementation periodically causes a bug when `this.items` does not receive yet (it is `undefined`) but `revenuesStreamsTotalCalculations` already gets with OnChanges or vise versa and extra recalculation. I need some solution to make sure I get ALL actual dependents. I have already tried to wrap `@Input` properties into `Observable` in parent component and combine dependents with `combineLatest` or `zip` but it looks too cumbersome. Could somebody advise any other possible workarounds?

```
export class PlanGroup implements OnInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy {
  @Input() items;
  @Input() revenuesStreamsTotalCalculations;

  constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    const { items, revenuesStreamsTotalCalculations } = changes;
    if (items && items.currentValue) { 
      this.calculateMetricsInformation(this.items, this.year, this.revenuesStreamsTotalCalculations);
    }
    if (revenuesStreamsTotalCalculations && revenuesStreamsTotalCalculations.currentValue) {
      this.calculateMetricsInformation(this.items, this.year, this.revenuesStreamsTotalCalculations);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route = this._route.params.pipe(
      takeUntil($unsubscribe),
      filter(p => p["year"])
    ).subscribe(p => {
      this.year = p["year"]
      if (this.revenuesStreamsTotalCalculations) {
        this.calculateMetricsInformation(this.items, this.year, this.revenuesStreamsTotalCalculations);
      }
    });
  }

  calculateMetricsInformation(items, year, revenuesStreamsTotalCalculations) {
    // ...implementation
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe you can use structural directive to render the component only when they are defined

Comment: Why you don't check for nulls `this.items` before processing it? `if(this.items)...` and when the data is available the changes are reflected.

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
<plan-group 
  *ngIf="items && revenuesStreamsTotalCalculations" 
  [items]="items" 
  [revenuesStreamsTotalCalculations]="revenuesStreamsTotalCalculations">
</plan-group>
```

in your parent component should do the trick - the PlanGroup component will never be initialized.

---

Also if both `items` and `revenuesStreamsTotalCalculations` are required you can move your checks to `calculateMetricsInformation` method:

```
  calculateMetricsInformation(items, year, revenuesStreamsTotalCalculations) {
    if (!items || !revenuesStreamsTotalCalculations) {
      return []; // or other empty value
    }
    //... implementation
  }
```